# Append A Random Number in every line in CSV file python

Tags: python, csv, random, append

I'm trying to append a random number in every line in csv file in row[2] i get the information from the original file then i write it to a new csv file + i append the second row with the random number 
but i get the same random number in every line when i run the script (
i have the read file which contain exp:

```
car,golf
```

when i write this data to new csv file and append the second row i get the same number for every line

```
car,golf,1777
car,bmw,1777
car,m3,1777
```

how can i fix this so i can have random number in every line

```
data = []  
    with open("read.csv", "r") as the_file:
        sid_row = 5000
        for i in range(sid_row):
            line = str(random.randint(1,5000))
            sid = line
        reader = csv.reader(the_file, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            try:
                new_row = [row[0], row[1],sid]
                data.append(new_row)
            except IndexError as error:
                print(error)
                pass
    with open("Random.csv", "w+") as Ran_file:
        writer = csv.writer(Ran_file, delimiter=",")
        for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: What's happening is that you are assigning a random number string to `sid` 5000 times, but you never use any of the values you generate except the very last one, because you only start actually adding that to your data after you've generated the last random number. You should be generating the random number each time you append a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new random number each time, for each row you're processing, something like:

```
data = []  
    with open("read.csv", "r") as the_file:
        reader = csv.reader(the_file, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            try:
                line = str(random.randint(1,5000))
                sid = line
                new_row = [row[0], row[1],sid]
                data.append(new_row)
            except IndexError as error:
                print(error)
                pass
    with open("Random.csv", "w+") as Ran_file:
        writer = csv.writer(Ran_file, delimiter=",")
        for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```